# Retrieving Column data from Sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, dataframe

I have created a db file from data downloaded from online. I used the following code to create the database:

```
    kiwoom.ohlcv = {'date': [], 'open': [], 'high': [], 'low': [], 'close': [], 'volume': []}
    df = pd.DataFrame(kiwoom.ohlcv, columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'], index=kiwoom.ohlcv['date'])

    con = sqlite3.connect("c:/Users/Runner/Data/Stock/Dayprice_kosdaq_filtered.db")
    df.to_sql(stock_code, con, if_exists='replace')
```

Here, the index data of the dataframe should have become an another column in the database according to the pandas.DataFrame documentation:

> index:bool, default True
> Write DataFrame index as a column. Uses index_label as the column name in the table.

The problem however is that if I try to call the data under index column using SELECT:

```
con1 = sqlite3.connect("c://Users//Runner//Data//Stock//Dayprice_kosdaq_filtered.db")
cursor = con1.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT 'index' FROM '101360' WHERE close = 24850")
table_list = cursor.fetchall()
print(table_list)
```

I get the following result, where '101360' is the table name and close is a column:

> runfile('C:/Users/Runner/Spyder Projects/Stocks/Get Data/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Runner/Spyder Projects/Stocks/Get Data')
> [('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',), ('index',)]

When I check the values for index column through DB Browser, I do see TEXT values of dates but when trying to access it via python code, I get 'index' values.
What has gone wrong and how could I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Remove the quotes around `index`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried so but I get a syntax error. I think its because index is a keyword. I guess the only way around it is to rename the column?

Comment: Yeah, `index` seems to be a keyword in sqlite. You can use `idx`, looks similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try covering the column (index, close) in the query with [] since both columns are keywords as below:

```
con1 = sqlite3.connect("c://Users//Runner//Data//Stock//Dayprice_kosdaq_filtered.db")
cursor = con1.cursor()
query = cursor.execute("SELECT [index] FROM '101360' WHERE [close] = 24850")
client_df = pd.DataFrame(query)
```